# Apple Match - O Linker (Id) Error

Tags: ipad, web-applications

I don't know what this error is saying. The retrievePatients method interacts with a WSDL file. What is the error exactly? What do I search for to fix it?
Thanks!

```
Ld /Users/chibb9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AllRelatedMethodsDemo-cixcxshgvqywvcgbqxcivzvomzuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AllRelatedMethodsDemo.app/AllRelatedMethodsDemo normal i386
    cd "/Users/chibb9/MEDiSN Research/AllRelatedMethodsDemo"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
-arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
-L/Users/chibb9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AllRelatedMethodsDemo-cixcxshgvqywvcgbqxcivzvomzuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/chibb9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AllRelatedMethodsDemo-cixcxshgvqywvcgbqxcivzvomzuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-filelist /Users/chibb9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AllRelatedMethodsDemo-cixcxshgvqywvcgbqxcivzvomzuf/Build/Intermediates/AllRelatedMethodsDemo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AllRelatedMethodsDemo.build/Objects-normal/i386/AllRelatedMethodsDemo.LinkFileList
-mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lxml2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/chibb9/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AllRelatedMethodsDemo-cixcxshgvqywvcgbqxcivzvomzuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AllRelatedMethodsDemo.app/AllRelatedMethodsDemo

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_retrievePatients", referenced from:
      -[MEDiSN20AidnWebServiceRunner run] in MEDiSN20AidnWebServiceRunner.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Download in Download.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Download in Download.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Download.h or .m, link against and `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`